# UPI integration with ionic app is not getting through

Tags: ionic-framework, deep-linking, upi

I have integrated my ionic App with UPI . Everything is happening perfectly like all the UPI apps are getting opened up for selection while doing payment , but when i am entering my upi pin . Always i am getting errors , payment is not happening . Tried with different different UPi apps but same issue . Please help me out

My code below :-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

import { WebIntent } from "@ionic-native/web-intent/ngx";

import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component(
             {
               selector: "app-cart",

              templateUrl: "./cart.page.html",

              styleUrls: ["./cart.page.scss"],

            })
export class CartPage implements OnInit {

  totalPrice:number;
  UPI_ID:string;
  UPI_TXN_NOTE:string;
  UPI_NAME:string;
  TXN_Ref:string;

  constructor(private webIntent: WebIntent,
              private router   : Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  weekly() {

    
    this.totalPrice = 10.00;
    this.UPI_ID = '1234567890@upi';
    this.UPI_NAME = 'test_KUMAR';
    this.UPI_TXN_NOTE = 'Weekly%20Package';
    this.TXN_Ref = '#Week001'
    const options = {
      action: this.webIntent.ACTION_VIEW,
      url:'upi://pay?pa=' + this.UPI_ID + '&pn=' + this.UPI_NAME + '&am=' + this.totalPrice + '&tn=' + this.UPI_TXN_NOTE + '&tr=' + this.TXN_Ref 
      };

      this.webIntent.startActivityForResult(options).then(
        (success)=>{
        
          console.log("Payment Succesfull",success);         
          
        },         
        err => {
          alert('error block' + err);
        }   
      
      );
  
    }
```

I have imported webintent in appmodule.ts also .. everything is done completely but still error is coming . Please check .

Error on App :-

[error  coming on phonepe app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NorES.jpg)

Comment: How was it solved?

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. You need to use a merchant upi id for the transactions made using deep linking

Comment: how to get merchant upi id?

Comment: You need to  Sign up for Google Pay for Business.
You can get more info here.
https://support.google.com/pay/business/answer/7684271?hl=en

Let me know if you still got stuck.
We did this successfully in our applications.

Comment: sure.on Razorpay i generated Marchant upi and its working thanks for your help